# Happy Flow Test case using Junit 4 for java servlet

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, code-coverage, junit4

I am trying to test my servlet class for happy flow using Junit 4. Even though the test is passing the code coverage is only 37%. Need help in understanding what is going wrong and how to rectify it.

**Test case**

```
public class SearchOrganizationTest extends Mockito{

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private final PrintStream originalOut = System.out;
    private final PrintStream originalErr = System.err;

    @Before
    public void setUpStreams() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(outContent));
        System.setErr(new PrintStream(errContent));
    }
    @After 
    public void restoreStreams() {
        System.setOut(originalOut);
        System.setErr(originalErr);
    }
    @Mock
    private Organization org;
    @InjectMocks
    SearchOrganization mockSearchOrganization;
    @Test //Test code for checking whether the Search Organization outer (invoking) function is working fine
    public void testServlet() throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);       
        HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);

        try {
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
            when(response.getWriter()).thenReturn(writer);

            new SearchOrganization().doPost(request, response); //calling the function with the dummy parameters
            System.out.print("hello");
            String res = outContent.toString();
            assertEquals(res, outContent.toString());
            System.err.print("hello again");
            assertEquals("hello again", errContent.toString());

            writer.flush(); // it may not have been flushed yet...
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

**SearchOrganization.class**

```
//Invoking the method on the submission of the form
@WebServlet("/viewOrganization")
public class SearchOrganization extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("SearchOrg.html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        //Getting the attributes from the UI

        try {
            DataConnection ds =new DataConnection();
            String org_name = request.getParameter("searchOrg");

            //Setting the objects to insert the achieved attributes to corresponding the columns of the table

            Organization searchOrg = new Organization();

            searchOrg.setOrgName(org_name);
            dispatcher.include(request, response);
            //calling and fetching the details recieved by the getOrganizations function from OrganizationDao class
            List<Organization> list = new OrganizationDao(ds).getOrganization(searchOrg);
            out.print("<h3 align = 'center'>Orgnanization Name</h3>");
            out.print("<table class= 'fixed_header' align= 'center' ");
            out.print("<thead>");
            out.print("</thead>");
            out.print("<tbody");  
            //listing the values fetched by the function to appropriate columns of a table 
            for(Organization e:list){  
                out.print("<tr><td style='padding:10px'><a href='SearchOrg.html?orgName="+e.getOrgName()+"'>"+e.getOrgName()+"</a></td></tr>");
            }  

            out.print("</tbody>");  
            out.print("</table>");

            out.close();
        }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println("SearchOrganizatin: doPost() - "+e);}
    }
}
```

*Here in the `dispatcher.include(request, response);` the test case is breaking the happy flow and is directly going to the `catch(Exception e) {System.out.println("SearchOrganizatin: doPost() - "+e);}` part.

I need to know how to ignore the `dispatcher.include(request, response);` so that it will continue the flow after that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the mocked `request` object and return a mocked dispatcher when `getParameter` is called.

something like

```java
when(request.getParameter(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mocked-dispatcher-object);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little so that i can understand what is happening through this code.. I am newbie in this @Smile

Comment: I tried to created a mocked dispatcher object but when i try `when(request.getParameter(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mocked-dispatcher-object);`  it says that `The method thenReturn(String) in the type OngoingStubbing<String> is not applicable for the arguments (RequestDispatcher)`  and if i change that to string then the test case is passing but the code coverage is not getting improved  @Smile

Comment: you might want to read question/answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357046/error-in-writing-junit-test-case-request-dispatcher